# Flink - Memory Consumption always increasing

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

NOTE: As the David suggestion, I have just updated my flink project to version v1.12.3. With v1.12.3, It seems flink has done some improvements. Right now, my problem is resolved.

---

My current flink application runs with 48 task slots on 3 nodes. Also I am using rocksdb as state management. (I do not care about Savepoints and Checkpoint mechanism about in flink, I am just creating state which almost 5 mins ttl)

However memory consumption for all nodes are always increasing and I have to do stop flink application via stop-cluster.sh, then re-start again.

I have many keyedstreams based on the client ip address. In daily basis, millions of users are visiting my site.

Some of the keyed streams are using `StateTtlConfig` while others using `onTimer` mechanism.

My assumption about memory consumption (or leak) is that: calling the registerProcessingTimer creates an entry which holds in memory and because there are many ip addresses I will have many entries and memory consumption is always increasing ?

**Should i remove onTimer solution and only using StateTtlConfig?** (I am using onTimer method because in StateTtlConfig every time I update the state it also updates the ttls which creates invalid data in my application)

Examples for state managements

```java
// EXAMPLE FOR STATETTLCONFIG
public class State1 extends KeyedProcessFunction<Tuple, ..., ...>{

    private transient ValueState<Integer> state;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception{

        StateTtlConfig ttlConfig = StateTtlConfig
                .newBuilder(Time.minutes(2))
                .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
                .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired)
                .cleanupInBackground()
                .build();

        ValueStateDescriptor<Integer> valueStateDesc = new ValueStateDescriptor<Integer>(
               ..
        );
        valueStateDesc.enableTimeToLive(ttlConfig);

        state = getRuntimeContext().getState(valueStateDesc);
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(LogObject value, Context ctx, Collector<LogObject> out) throws Exception{
        Integer stateVal = valueState.value();
        // do something and update state
    }
}

// EXAMPLE FOR ONTIMER METHOD

public class State2 extends KeyedProcessFunction<Tuple, ..., ...> {

    private transient ValueState<Integer> state;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters){

        ValueStateDescriptor<Integer> stateDesc = new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
                ...;

        state = getRuntimeContext().getState(stateDesc);
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(LogObject value, Context ctx, Collector<LogObject> out) throws Exception{
        Integer stateVal = state.value();

        if (stateVal == null)
        {
            stateVal = 0;
            ctx.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(value.getTimestamp() + 5 MINS);
        }
        stateVal ++;
        // do something and update state
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<LogObject> out)
    {
        stateVal.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: How many keys do you have approximately ?

Comment: In one day totally, I have (+, -) 3.000.000 distinct ip address, (which 3.000.000 keys)
If I group the total distinct ip addresses according to the 5 mins, at min I have (+, -)16.000 ip addresses, at most I have (+, -)300.000

Comment: What version of Flink are you using? There were problems with RocksDB using too much memory in some of the recent releases. Have you tried 1.11.3 or 1.12.2?

Comment: @DavidAnderson, I am using version 1.10.1, (verified via flink dashboard), and also I realized that when build my application via maven, i am using the flink-version = 1.9.1, after packing my application as jar, ı deployed the jar via dashboard

Comment: It’s not a good idea to mix versions, and you should upgrade to the latest bug fix release of whatever minor version you want to be using. I’d suggest you at least update the server to 1.10.3 and use the same version on the client.

Comment: @DavidAnderson, I just packaged my application via maven version 1.10.1, but nothing changed, what could be the other factors? Do you have any idea? And also what can you say about onTimer solution ( registerProcessingTimer creates an entry which holds.... )

Comment: As I said earlier, I urge you to move to either 1.11.3 or 1.12.2. There were memory allocation problems with RocksDB on older versions like the one you're using.

Comment: Using timers does provide more direct control over state retention than state TTL.

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson, before moving to the v12.2 , i just checked the graphics again, and I realized that Flink Task Manager Heap Usage always increasing (flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap_Used), is this also normal? (related to the rocksdb ?)

Comment: That’s interesting, and not related to RocksDB.